# How can I use regex to replace the last comma in a price?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, format

Given the price 1,200,00.I would like to replace the last comma with a period and remove the first comma so that i can get the following format: 1200.00

How could I do this using regex, please dont suggest any other methods to do this because I need to use regex in the following javascript:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call($(".price.inline")).map(function(v){ 
    return v.textContent.replace(/€\s/gi,"").replace(/regex goes here/gi,"";}
)
```

I am trying to query the price from the following website: http://www.bechtle.es/shop/BD_ES/NETGEAR+WC7529SKT+Wireless+Starterkit_828784?pixelSource
but I need to format it in North American currency with periods instead of commas thats why I need to get rid of the first comma and replace the second one with a period

Comment: That code snippet does not show any reason to use a regex, does it?

Comment: If you can't use other methods, this sounds like homework. What have you tried?

Comment: Just a note: the numbers on the website you link aren't even formatted like that. They are using a `.` as a group separator and `,` as the decimal separator, so `1.200,00`. I'm not aware of any culture that uses the same symbol for both group and decimal separator as that would be *horribly* confusing.

Comment: Also, there are several "North American" Currencies, and don't you need to do some actual math to convert them? Just replacing € with $ doesn't cut it.

Comment: Sorry about that i completely got confused, i shouldnt have asked this question but now i cant delete it
sorry about this

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
s='1,200,00';
s.replace(/,(?=[^,]*$)/, ".").replace(/,+/g, "");
//=> 1200.00
```

Answer (score 3):

Try breaking this up into several calls. First, remove the last comma and replace with a period. Then remove all the other commas and replace with an empty string.

E.g.,

```
var x = '1,200,00',
    y = x.replace(/,(\d+)$/, '.$1'),
    z = y.replace(/,/g, '');
```

See a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/U8ya3/